# Slow performance of only puppet commands on Learning Puppet VM

Tags: puppet

I'm using the [Learning Puppet VM](http://info.puppetlabs.com/download-learning-puppet-VM.html) in VirtualBox and am getting slow performance (1 to 2 *minutes* per command) specifically for `puppet` commands.

`puppet` itself is oblivious to these performance issues, reporting response times as under a second:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for learn.localdomain in environment production in 0.15 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]//User[katie]/ensure: removed
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.45 seconds
```

Since normal Linux commands like `ls` execute instantaneously, I'm assuming this is not an issue of the VM needing more memory or CPU allocation from VirtualBox. Is there a way to configure `puppet` on the VM to increase performance?

Comment: Where does the delay occur - before the "compiled catalog" notice?

Comment: Yes. No output at all for 1-2 minutes.

Comment: How about with `--verbose --debug` added to the command?

Comment: After about 30 seconds, I get a host of `Info: Loading facts` statements, followed 30 seconds later by more `Info: Loading facts` and `Debug:` statements, followed 1 minute later by the output of the command, with `puppet` reporting that the command took `0.29 seconds` to run.

Comment: That's.. pretty horrible.  How much RAM does the VM have?  What kind of physical disk is it running on?

Comment: I have it set up with the default 1024MB. I'm running it on a Macbook Pro with a SATA 500 GB (5400 RPM) disk.

Comment: Which specific command string(s) are you running?

Comment: Any puppet command in the first parts of the learning exercises runs this slow. For example, `puppet apply /root/examples/file-1.pp`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it's excruciating.  The one answer about adding the VM's IP address into /etc/host didn't appear to resolve the problem.

Comment: And I stand corrected: I hadn't correctly set up the name on the domain.  Upvoted both this question and the correct answer, of course.

Answer (score 3):

it's a network problem.
You have to put the IP adress of your running VM into /etc/host (in the puppet-learning VM!) !
For example:
10.211.55.6 learn.puppetlabs.vm learn

Thats all! :)